# Google Maps runs GPS in background even if the GPS radio is off - how do I fix?

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, battery-life, gps, google-maps, lg-g2

*I have the T-Mobile version of the LG G2, running Android 4.2.2, everything stock except the keyboard. I'm not sure what version of Google Maps, but the Play Store says it's up to date.*

Yesterday I noticed that the G2's battery was draining a lot faster than it had been. I had thought it was just because I had been listening to music a lot more that day, but then when I checked the battery app that night it said that Google Maps was responsible for *half* the battery drain. I had used it earlier that morning for directions and it had apparently run the GPS in the background for 11 hours straight. I thought it was a one-off, but it happened again today. I've attached a screenshot.

The GPS on my device is *off* as far as I can tell (i.e. the visual indicator in the tray is dark), so I don't know whether Google Maps is turning it on stealthily and forgetting to turn it off, or whether it's trying to find a GPS signal, can't because the radio is off, and gets stuck in a loop looking for it. I'm assuming the former because there's no CPU activity, just GPS. When I click the "Location Services" button, these are the settings:

- Access to my location: **ON**
- GPS Satellites: **OFF**
- Wi-Fi & mobile network location: **ON**

So it shouldn't be happening. Why does this happen and how can I fix it? I suppose I can just remember to force stop Google Maps every time I use it, but I'm hoping for a better solution.

[image: Screenshot]
<sup>Screenshot (click for larger variant)</sup>

Comment: Also, I just discovered that the GPS drain doesn't stop when I force kill the process. Could my GPS just be broken?

Comment: Google Maps does that. That's why I froze it, and only unfreeze it when I need it. Is your device rooted? Is Google Maps installed as system-app, or did you install it yourself?

Comment: Came pre-installed. And, no, as I said, everything is stock - not rooted.

Comment: In that case, I'm afraid there's not much you can do. Rooted+UserApp would give you the option of using Greenify. Without the two, you could go to *Settings→Apps*, scroll to *Google Maps*, and "disable" it – but that can just be done after uninstalling its updates, which is not quite convenient (as whenever you need it, you'd have to "enable" it again, and wait for the updates to be re-installed or use the old version; plus switching on/off requires too many steps). Of course you could disable it, and use a different maps/navigation app altogether.

Comment: So this is a known issue? Can you point me to the bug report, because I can't seem to find it. I'd like to track the progress.

Comment: I don't know about a "bug report" on this. But yes, it's known behaviour. First app I freeze is Maps, because otherwise it permanently runs in background without me ever having started it. And I know I'm not the only one with this. Sorry I cannot point you to anything to track.

Comment: Well freezing it seems to be a solution, and I'm honestly not sure what you mean by that, so why don't you elaborate in an answer? :)

Comment: Done. Hope it's not too technical, but at least understandable :)

Answer (score 3):

*Google Maps* is known for situations like this for years. It doesn't happen all the time and on all devices simultaneously with all versions of maps, but comes often enough. For me, the decision was to disable/freeze *Google Maps*, and use other Map apps (Locus Map, OruxMaps) instead. But let's go into details how an app (in your case *Google Maps*) can be "put on ice":

### On a rooted device

A rooted device gives you the most alternatives. Say you want to use the app from time to time, you could use the following approach:

#### Dynamic freeze

1. convert *Google Maps* from system-app to user-app. This can be done e.g. with [Titanium Backup](http://www.appbrain.com/app/titanium-backup-%E2%98%85-root/com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup) – and is of course not necessary if *Maps* didn't ship with your device (but was explicitly installed by yourself, which already makes it a "user-app")
2. [Greenify](http://www.appbrain.com/app/greenify-%2aroot%3A-renew-my-phone/com.oasisfeng.greenify) *Maps*. This way the app is kept from running unless you explicitly start it. You could think of this as a "dynamic freeze"

#### Static freeze

If you do not need the app anyway, and rather use another replacement, you can freeze it permanently. A freeze marks an app as being "unavailable", so it can no longer be started. There are multiple apps which can handle this, as e.g. before mentioned [Titanium Backup](http://www.appbrain.com/app/titanium-backup-%E2%98%85-root/com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup) or [App Quarantine](http://www.appbrain.com/app/app-quarantine-root-freeze/com.ramdroid.appquarantine). Using *Titanium Backup* would give you an advantage here: *TiBu* let's you place a shortcut on your homescreen to freeze/unfreeze-start an app, basically emulating the "dynamic freeze" described above. No need to convert the app into an user-app for this.

#### Disabling Auto-Start on certain events

Many apps register so-called "broadcast receivers" to be notified on system events they are interested in. The best known certainly is `boot_completed` for apps that want to become active right after the device has booted up – but there are a lot more. Examples include the change of network status (true for our *Google Maps* candidate), battery-low, or the SDCard being mounted. On a rooted device, you can disable those "listeners" with so-called "Autostart managers". One of the best is [Autorun Manager](http://www.appbrain.com/app/autorun-manager-pro/com.rs.autorun.pro) in its Pro-Version. If using those, take care to not disable too much, as that might render an app unusable.

### Without root

Without root, I know of only one way to achieve something comparable:

1. Go to *Settings→Apps*
2. Select the "All" tab
3. Scroll to the app in question (here: Google Maps), and tap its entry
4. If you don't see a "Disable" button, but "uninstall updates" instead, it's a system app. Tap "uninstall updates", then "force stop".
5. Tap the "Disable" button

Now the app is de-activated, and *should* no longer run. I explicitly made "should" in italics, as to my experience often this is only a partial working solution: though the app is removed from the drawer, it seems it's still not completely out-of-reach for certain frameworks.

### Pros and Cons

- Disable: Only available solution if your device is not rooted.

  - Pro: does not require root
  - Cons:
  - app not always completely disabled
  - no dynamics
  - requires multiple "taps"
  - requires to always uninstall updates first (if there are any)
  - not applyable to all apps (manufacturer/carrier can "lock" apps against this)
- Static Freeze:

  - Pros:
  - Works on all apps
  - Partly dynamic (using *TiBu* and its "shortcuts" on your homescreen)
  - Con: Requires root
- Dynamic Freeze:

  - Pros:
  - Dynamic
  - app icons remain in the drawer/on your home screens (so from the user's perspective, handling remains unchanged)
  - Cons:
  - requires root
  - doesn't work on system apps (though there are "experimental features" for this AFAIK).