# How can i make my google maps app close?

Tags: google-maps

I used google maps earlier today and now it won't close. I exited the navigation, even restarted my phone, and it's still showing as running in the background. How do I make it close? I have an LG V10.

Comment: Welcome to the Android Enthusiasts! Please see: [Why is Google Maps always running in the background?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/33548/16575) / [Google Maps runs GPS in background even if the GPS radio is off - how do I fix?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/57387/16575) / [Is there a way to permanently turn off Google Maps until needed?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/19000/16575)

Answer (score 1):

I spent a long time trying to figure this out and then I accidentally solved it. When you hit the square button to see all the apps running you will see a "pin" next to the "x" which is what you would normally click on to close a running up. If that pin is highlighted the app keeps running. Just tap it to deselect it and then you can close the app normally.

I read a lot of crazy solutions that required rooting and other stuff. It turns out that things work they should I just wasn't aware of the pin button and what it did. I hope you find this useful

Answer (score 0):

I went into setting, did a force stop and then at the top of the page there was a slider I turned to "off" and it fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

On my android phone, I tap the home button and it takes me to the navigation app home page. Then I tap the back arrow and it gives me an dialog asking if I want to exit the app.

Comment: What you're describing doesn't sound like Google Maps. Is this some other navigation app? The question is specifically about Google Maps.

Answer (score 0):

on my phone i swiped up from the bottom, which allowed me to see my home button(circle) which i could tap , then went to running apps(the square button on bottom row)  and could then swipe sideways to close google maps